# How to change randomly the dates of creation and modification of files

Tags: r

I need to change the files creation / modification dates for an exercice.

According to http://theautomatic.net/2018/12/18/how-to-change-file-last-modified-date-with-r/ , I can find files info with `file.info()`function.

I can also change the dates modification of all the files in a folder combining `sapply` and `Sys.setFileTime` :

```
 sapply(list.files("path", full.names = TRUE), 
              function(FILE) Sys.setFileTime(FILE, "1975-01-01"))
```

How can I also change date of creation ? (ctime <S3: POSIXct>)

What I expect : for the exercice : I want to change randomly the dates of creation and modification of files (in a range of a year, files are not are created at the same day)

What I tried  (changing only date of modification) :

```
     sapply(list.files("C:/Users/cariou-w/Nextcloud/sync-uncloud/1920-1921/master/web_scrapping/plans", full.names = TRUE), 
      function(FILE) Sys.setFileTime(FILE, paste0("2020-11-", sample(days,1))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic cross platform way to change file creation time in R - many file systems do not even track it. You can use `system` or `system2` to call whatever the appropriate shell command is for you. E.g. on OS X, `touch -t 202001011234 /path/to/my/file`